# A better way to write multiple if-conditions in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my code involving multiple if-conditions. Is there a better way to write it? It looks a bit messy. I am sure python has some design pattern or built-in functions for that.

Thanks in advance.

```
ui_site_groups = []
ui_sites = []
ui_departments = []
department_refs_uuid = []
site_uuids = []
site_group_refs_uuid = [] 
for key, val in topo_map.iteritems():
  if obj_type == 'SITE':
      if key == 'site':
          ui_sites.append(val)
      if key == 'site_uuid':
          site_uuids.append(val)
  if obj_type == 'SITE-GROUP':
      if key == 'site-group':
          ui_site_groups.append(val)
      if key == 'site-group_refs_uuid':
          site_group_refs_uuid.append(val)
  if obj_type == 'DEPARTMENT':
      if key == 'department':
          ui_departments.append(val)
      if key == 'department_refs_uuid':
          department_refs_uuid.append(val)
```

Comment: You should use `elif` for mutually-exclusive tests.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks more fitting in CodeReview

Comment: Do you really need to test for the `obj_type` before testing the key? Could there be a mismatch?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be on topic on [codereview.se] either, its hard to say if theres a better way of writing it without fully understanding what output its supposed to be giving

Comment: Do you even need the check on obj_type? isn't it already enough to check on the level of key?

Comment: What do you consider "better"?

Comment: https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html
is this good for you?

Comment: Each case consists of testing 3 items and modifying certain variables. This could be put into a table of 3 entries and each entry could be "executed".

Answer (score 3):

You could use dictionary lookup instead of if statements:

```
ui_site_groups = []
ui_sites = []
ui_departments = []
department_refs_uuid = []
site_uuids = []
site_group_refs_uuid = [] 

key_to_list = {('SITE', 'site'): site_uuids,
               ('SITE', 'site_uuid'): site_uuids,
               ('SITE-GROUP', 'site-group'): ui_site_groups,
               ('SITE-GROUP', 'group_refs_uuid'): site_group_refs_uuid,
               ('DEPARTMENT', 'department') : ui_departments,
               ('DEPARTMENT', 'department_refs_uuid'): department_refs_uuid}


for key, val in topo_map.iteritems():
    if (obj_type, key) in key_to_list:
        key_to_list[(obj_type, key)].append(val)
```

Comment: What I'm wondering is what `topo_map` looks like. Does it contain keys that should be ignored? Why do they want to append to lists? There's not more than one value matching any key in `topo_map`?

Comment: I think my version does the same as OPs, doesn't matter if there are values to be ignored.

Comment: this should work for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can easily do it with an 'or' function

Basically, you can do:

```
ui_sites = []
ui_departments = []
department_refs_uuid = []
site_uuids = []
site_group_refs_uuid = [] 
  for key, val in topo_map.iteritems():
        if obj_type == 'SITE' or obj_type == 'SITE-GROUP' or obj_type == 'DEPARTMENT':
            if key == 'site'':
                ui_sites.append(val)
            if key == 'site_uuid':
                site_uuids.append(val)
            if key == 'site-group':
                ui_site_groups.append(val)
            if key == 'site-group_refs_uuid':
                site_group_refs_uuid.append(val)
            if key == 'department':
                ui_departments.append(val)
            if key == 'department_refs_uuid':
                department_refs_uuid.append(val)***
```

Also, when you do what you stated above, you risk a chance of both happening and it recuring twice(although not happenening here)

Example:
I want to check if x == y or x > 0. If so, print(x
I put:

```
x = int(input("Enter either a negative number or a positive number"))

y = int(input("Enter either a negative number or a positive number"))

if x == y:

    print(x)

if x > 0:

    print(x)
```

But what if x is 2, y is also 2?
It prints out x two times.
However, with the 'or' statement, it will only print it once even if both statements are True.

Hope you find the answer useful. Thanks

Comment: this will not work for my case. anyway thanks for your time.